# Signalr connection issue in Visual Studio Load Test

Tags: signalr, load-testing

I am trying to run load test on my application containing signalr. When I run the application, all its requests get recorded. My app runs smoothly till this point. But when system runs my application through the recorded session then it is throwing an error on "Signalr/connect" method. It says, connectionId is invalid.

I didnt call "signalr/connect" method directly. I just called "$.connection.hub.start();" in my javascript. "connect" call is signalr internal call which is expecting a connectionId.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: This article is a bit old but you might be better looking at crank. https://www.dotnetcurry.com/signalr/914/stress-testing-signalr-crank-utility

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are also a limited number of connections you can make on your localhost using IIS express which might be causing your invalid connections. The article Steve pointed to using Crank is a better option for load testing connections to see what your app/server can handle.